# ListView1 not declared it may be due to its protection level

Tags: vb.net, variables, methods, visual-studio-2015

[image: Interface screenshot]

```
Dim rtb As New RichTextBox
    rtb.AppendText("Generation, Num Of Juveniles, Num of Adults, Num of Semiles, Total" & vbNewLine)
    For Each saveitem As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        rtb.AppendText(
                         saveitem.Text & ", " &
                        saveitem.SubItems(1).Text & ", " &
                       saveitem.SubItems(2).Text & ", " &
                      saveitem.SubItems(3).Text & ", " &
                     saveitem.SubItems(4).Text & vbNewLine)
    Next
    rtb.SaveFile("C:\Users\SMITH\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test.txt",
      RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
End Sub

Private Sub Results_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Call Init(ListView1.Items)

End Sub
```

I keep getting the error listview1 is not declared it may be due to its protection level. I am new to VB and have been working on this for a while. Does anyone have a coded solution to this or could point me in the write direction. It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please show your .designer file... I have a feeling you are missing a `Friend WithEvents` in that file which would yield that error.

Comment: Do you actually have a `ListView` control named `ListView1` in that form?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: no my listview control is in another form...

Comment: @Zaggler I have added an image in my post for the menu screen. The export button is where the code I have just posted is. The listview I have is in the run buttons form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the ListView1 from aonther form as Form1.ListView1

Comment: Thanks. I now have anoher error on my Results Load sub. It says 'Value of type listview.listviewitemcollection cannot be converted to a listview' Any ideas ?

Comment: You may want to change `Call Init(ListView1.Items)` into `Call Init(ListView1)`

Comment: Thanks everyone. Everything's now running however, the data from my listview isn't writing to my textfile. Any ideas?